# DecodeError in Paramiko Remote File

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a large remote file that is generated automatically each day. I have no control over how the file is generated. I'm using Paramiko to open the file and then search through it to find if a given line matches a line in the file.

However, I'm receiving the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 57: invalid start byte

My code:

```
self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=pass)

self.sftp_client = self.ssh.open_sftp()
self.remote_file = self.sftp_client.open(filepath, mode='r')

def checkPhrase(self, phrase):
    found = 0
    self.remote_file.seek(0)
    for line in self.remote_file:
        if phrase in line:
            found = 1
            break
    return found
```

I'm receiving the error at the line: `for line in self.remote_file:` Obviously there is a character in the file that is out of the range for utf8.

Is there a way to re-encode the line as it's read or to simply ignore the error?

Answer (score -1):

So, files are bytes. They may or may not have some particular encoding. Additionally, [paramiko is always returning bytes](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.file), since it ignores the `'b'` flag that normal `open` functions take.

Instead, you should try and decode each line yourself. First, open the file in binary mode, then read a line, then *try* to decode that line as `utf-8`. If that fails, just skip the line.

```
def checkPhrase(self, phrase):
    self.remote_file.seek(0)
    for line in self.remote_file:
        try:
            decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')  # Decode from bytes to utf-8
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue  # just keep processing other lines in the file, since this one it's utf-8

        if phrase in decoded_line:
            return True  # We found the phrase, so just return a True (instead of 1)
    return False  # We never found the phrase, so return False (instead of 0)
```

Additionally, i've found Ned Batcheldar's [Unipain pycon talk](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) immensly helpful in understanding bytes vs unicode.